# When Autodesk Forge Model deleted from transient bucket after 24 hours, still can view this model from Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, forge, aps

I uploaded and translated many files to transient bucket from Autodesk Forge API and after 24 hours, uploaded models deleted but still  can view these models with model's urn from Forge Viewer.Esspecialy when i use to "https://models.autodesk.io/view.html?urn={modelurn}?token={yourtoken}" link for view these models,still can view.I think this site make GET request to "https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/{modelurn}?domain=https%3A%2F%2Fmodels.autodesk.io" and in this way, the viewer model works even though they are deleted after 24 hours from transient bucket.

How does this happen? Does Autodesk keep a copy of this model in the cache in the back? If so, how long does it keep it?

I want to be able to explain what exactly it does as a mechanism, I want to understand

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this blog post](https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/01/buckets-in-autodesk-view-and-data-api.html), translated viewable contents(knows as derivatives) do not expire with the seed objects in transient or temporary bucket.